# No option to add EDMX file to project in MVC solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I've created an MVC application. I would like to now add a new class-library project to the solution, and then add an EDMX file to that project.

This used to be easy. But now I have to choose between .NET Core and .NET Standard. But it appears it doesn't matter which I choose because if I create a class library with either of these frameworks, Visual Studio provides no option for adding an EDMX file to them! And I don't see an option to add a standard .NET Frameworks class library.

So what is the secret incantation to add a new project to my MVC solution, and then add an EDMX file to that project?

*Note: I do have the option of adding an EDMX file directly to the MVC project. But I would prefer to place it in a separate project, which I've done before.*

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? This is MVC Core or the asp.net MVC 6? If it is an ASP.NET Core Web App, what framework do you use Full .NET Framework or Core? And what do you mean you don't see the option to add .NET Framework class library? in the Add new project > Windows Desktop > Class Librarly (.NET Framework) template is missing for you?

Comment: @TamásHuj I just went into Visual Studio and selected a new MVC solution. It appears to have built a project for the regular, full .NET app. Are there now multiple ways to create MVC apps?

Comment: Yes, there is, now there are 2 different MVC frameworks, the old ASP.NET MVC and the new ASP.NET Core MVC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC the first one is using the Full .NET Framework, and the second is implemented in .NET Core and it is cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

EDMX file is deprecated with EF Core and I believe it has been removed from .net core projects as well.
If you need to do that, you may need to add it to a normal .net 4.5 project and copy the files but this will make no sense using it with .net core or .net standard.

You should be using Code First anyway as it is cleaner and easier to use.

If you already have the database, you can refer to this link, it can help you to scaffold the classes from the database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: I just want to use Entity Framework. How are the models built if not in an EDMX file?

Comment: EDMX file is just one old way of using EF. The recommended way is to use Code First. This where you define the Context class and the entity classes and use something called Migration to create your database and whenever you need to update the database, you just edit the entity classes that map to the tables and create a new migration which will script only the changes and apply it through the database. Follow the link I shared to know more

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can still use Entity Framework without using code first.

Comment: You can and you can do that by copying the files from a standard .net 4.5 project but in this case it will not be a .net core project and better to go with normal full .net project and you will be using something that is deprecated

Comment: Having to copy files from a different type of project is not support for something. This used to be supported. Now I'm hearing it isn't. I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan: The EDMX file is old way of doing things. EDMX is nothing but a T4 template which facilitates in creation of edmx.

With .Net Core the best way is to:
1. Create a .net core library project. Add entityframeworkcore nuget package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/)
2. The use this link, to [generate your model's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model) from DB

The concept of EDMX is not supported anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that, where previously support for Entity Framework was built in, I now need to download packages? Why is this moving backwards?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description you're using the old ASP.NET MVC framework, and not the new Core one, and in this case you're using the Full .NET framework. So, when you create the new Class Library project, you should do it with the Full .NET Framework, because .NET Core and .NET Standard does not support, EDMX. If you chose this one, you can add your ADO.NET Entity Data model to it:

[image]

Comment: But I think you can add a Core project to a solution that already has a Standard project. So I'm not sure why it matters what my existing project uses.

Comment: Standard is compatible with Core and full .NET Framework. This means, that you can add The Standard to an existing Core project or to an existing full .NET Framework project. But as they mention in the other comments, Core and Standard does not support EDMX, so if you want to use it you'll need the full .NET Framework, this is what I tried to explain, that you'll need to add the Class Library with the full .NET Framework.

Answer (score -1):

At least for EF v6, if your using EF Migrations, each ('state'/'target') snapshot of the database (stored within the migrations-history db table & migration file) is an EDMX file just waiting to be decoded, saved to a file, and then loaded in VS (Visual Studio).   ;)

It's a little in-depth (or at least challenging), but 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor' may present the clue.

Basically, you can extract the EDMX from one/the relevant migration.  But I do agree that the Code-First approach should be used for the implementation, the EDMX is only a development-aid these days.

Comment: Pretty vague what you say here. If you're suggesting that an EDMX can be built from info in the migrations table you're wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm right - at least as far as EFv6, you just need to know how to do it; here's a clue - see 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor'.

Comment: We're not doing escape rooms here. Your answer should be clear, not just a vague hint. It's not clear how this helps OP simply to add an EDMX to their project while in Visual Studio.

Comment: I was trying to point out that an EDMX might already be available under the hood - prime for the picking & to build upon, within the migrations-history table, but I didn't want to overload this topic with what is possibly a less direct answer/solution.